# how to re-enable Media Device (MTP) for USB PC Connection Samsung Galaxy s2

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb-connection-mode, mtp

I cant connect my phone the normal way it used to be on PCs where i used SU command on ADB shell to access system files of my phone. I'm just guessing that the phone is storing the identity of the PC where SU is used. Can i just delete files or modify settings so i can access my files thru MTP again?[image: This is what im getting when connected to usb device as Media Device (MTP)]

Comment: Is MTP selected in USB Connection mode on device?

Comment: yes. just to add, it connects to the pc whenever i used mass storage device. but it takes a while to finish in the "Preparing SD Card" part